# PostgreSQL: IS NOT NULL statement not working

Tags: postgresql, postgis

If I use the statement

`SELECT * FROM dump WHERE (x_orig IS NOT NULL) OR (x_dest IS NOT NULL);`
[image: Not null image result]

It does not filter out the null values in the columns I indicate. But when I use the statement
`SELECT * FROM dump WHERE (x_orig IS NULL) OR (x_dest IS NULL);`
[image: Null image result]

It does filter out the results I actually want to remove.

I try to remove all the rows that have null values in the x coordinate of their origin or destination.

Comment: Check your screenshots, your SQL and the results do match. You get what you ask for.

Comment: It seems to be working correctly. What were you expecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) if you want to negate (A OR B) you need to change it to (!A **AND** !B) instead of (!A **OR** !B).

Comment: Thanks for the explaination, I only got a brief introduction to SQL and no theory, since I do not study comp sci.

Answer (score 1):

Does the `OR` in your original statement not just need to become `AND`?

`SELECT * FROM dump WHERE (x_orig IS NOT NULL) AND (x_dest IS NOT NULL);`

Then you are selecting all entries where both fields are non-null